# pgfplots log10 plot stops near 0

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to plot lg(x) with the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
    \centering\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=center,
            xmin = -1.2,
            ymin = -5.2,
            xmax = 5.2,
            ymax = 5.2,
            ylabel=$y$,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ]
            \addplot [domain=-1:5,samples=1000,thick, blue ] {log10(x)}
            node [pos=0.6, above left] {$f(x)=\lg x$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But the graph doesn't reach all the way down like it should. How can I change this behavior?

Comment: log(-1) is not defined.  log(0) is not a real number ($-\infty$).  Why would you want to plot them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value is only calculated in 1000 points, and that is not enough close to the y-axis. Instead of increasing the `samples` to an absurd value, you can just pull the point down yourself like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
    \centering\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            axis lines=center,
            xmin = -1.2,
            ymin = -5.2,
            xmax = 5.2,
            ymax = 5.2,
            ylabel=$y$,
            xlabel=$x$,
            ]
            \addplot [domain=-1:5,samples=1000,thick, blue,y filter/.expression={y<-2?\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin}:y}] {log10(x)}
            node [pos=0.8, above left] {$f(x)=\lg x$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph]

You can also get the same result by being creative with how the samples are distributed with e.g.:

```
samples at ={0.00000001,0.01,0.02,...,5}
```